# Upload image in strapi repeatable components

Tags: strapi

I have user_feedback in repeatable component in user table, how can I upload image to the newly added user feedback in strapi v3.

What currently I am doing

```
const data = await strapi.services["users"].update(
  { id: id },
  {
    ...updatedData,
  }
);
const newFeedback =
  data.feedback_prototype_phase[data.feedback_prototype_phase.length - 1];
await strapi.entityService.uploadFiles(data, files, {
  id: data.id,
  model: "user.user_feedback",
  field: "image",
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited this answer, Its best to

1. Upload the image to Media-Folder, via http://localhost:1337/api/upload
2. Then use the same URL http://localhost:1337/api/upload and include this in your request as the doc says in https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/plugins/upload.html#examples

````
<form>
  <!-- Can be multiple files if you setup "collection" instead of "model" -->
  <input type="file" name="files" />
  <input type="text" name="ref" value="api::restaurant.restaurant" />
  <input type="text" name="refId" value="5c126648c7415f0c0ef1bccd" />
  <input type="text" name="field" value="cover" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  const form = document.querySelector('form');

  form.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    await fetch('/api/upload', {
      method: 'post',
      body: new FormData(e.target)
    });
  });
</script>```

Your ref-id will be the ID of your entry, by entry It means the ID of your table's row or in no-sql you would say your document id.

Your ref is your service name as it suggests, your table name per say

Your field is the name of the field of the entry you want to upload the media too

Your files is simple the files that you want to upload

I would highly recommend you to use the template code given on docs then modify it, Instead of working on it directly. Thats what I did.
````

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32567375)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).